# Classic Asp Application pool hanging and generate freezes

Tags: asp-classic

```
Dim objXMLHTTP,xml,gString 
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 xml.Open "GET", "http://www.ourdomain.com/checkout/receiptdisplay.asp?orderid=" & ORDERNUMBER , False
xml.Send
ObjSendMail.HTMLBody    =   xml.responseText  
Set xml = Nothing
```

I am talking about very often situations that for some unknown reason, IIS Application Pool hangs and most classic ASP sites do not load (loading forever) and then i have to recycle application pool to make all work.

i use defaultAppPool for website.

Comment: This is a rather broad question.  Firstly, if I were you, I would look at the logs from IIS to try and work out what's taking the longest.  Look for any errors, also. After that, try assessing the objects and files that you're using to see if they're available when you use them.

Comment: I checked all thing and this code is hang or freezes app pool

Comment: Have you tried calling the address directly using your browser? i.e. `http://www.ourdomain.com/checkout/receiptdisplay.asp?orderid=123`?

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why?

Comment: yes it directly working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your application in to different app pools if certain parts are more memory intensive than others.  Instead of using `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`, which may be causing your issue, use a newer version:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

On another note, If you're doing HTTPRequests to the same website in the same application pool, you'll experience thread starving, which will cause issues like this.  To help resolve this, you need to separate them in their own application pools, like this:

This `HTTPRequest` script should be in one Application Pool

and your `receiptdisplay.asp` script should be in a different Application pool.

Microsoft goes more into detail why you should do this here:
[Do Not Send ServerXMLHTTP or WinHTTP Requests to the Same Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316451)